# Diophantine Equation $3n^2 + 4tn + kr^2 + f = s^2$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to make the following equation a square by adding a value I've called $f$:

$3n^2 + 4tn + kr^2 + f = s^2$

All the other variables are well defined and the equation pertains to integer factorisation. If $C$ is the number to be factorised, it may be written as $t^2 - kr^2$ where $t$ is the ceiling function of the square root of $C$.

But $C$ may also be written as $y^2 - x^2$ where $y$ and $x$ are derived as:

$y^2 = n^2 + 2tn + t^2$

$x^2 = n^2 + 2tn + kr^2$

We're not interested in the trivial solution where $n$ is given by $(C+1)/2 - t$
but rather only the one where $n$ is equal to $y$ minus $t$, i.e.

$n = y - t$

Incidentally, $y$ and $x$ are simply $(b+a)/2$ and $(b-a)/2$ respectively. The original equation that I'm trying to find a suitable $f$ value for whilst maintaining the constancy of $n$ is given by taking the $x^2$ equation and adding $2ny$ to it, which is just $2n(t+n)$. There will always be multiple $f$ values which when added to $x^2 + 2ny$ result in it becoming a square, but the question is twofold, how to find these $f$ values WITHOUT factorising $C$ beforehand, and secondly ensuring that the original $n$ value is still valid, i.e. remains unchanged in the equation, in equalling the square $s^2$. (i.e. the only change is the addition of $f$).

I have a feeling there is a simple solution to be found somewhere, I've just not been able to find it as of yet, so would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you streamlined this post into a single, easy-to-understand question. I can't tell what question you're asking.

Comment: I'll try. So basically $3n^2 + 4tn + kr^2$ by itself generally won't ever equal a square. By adding a suitable $f$ value, it will make this equation into a square, and this information can then (basically) be used to factorise $C$. The problem, or difficulty, is how to find a suitable $f$ value (or values) without requiring that $n$ changes its value, so that the equation $x^2 = n^2 + 2tn + kr^2$ still also applies, and both it and $3n^2 + 4tn + kr^2 + f$ are satisfied by the same $n$ value.

Comment: Update: I've found a solution, which I'll post here in a few hours once I've finished understanding it myself, why and how it works. But thanks. Maybe just having eyeballs on the problem helps in some strange way.

Comment: I've found a solution, in which crops up seemingly random Pythagorean triples, but the mechanism remains far from clear. Will post back here in the next few days once I've investigated further. It seems quite complicated and I don't fully understand the ins and outs just yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but essentially the solution to this problem lies in quasi-Pythagorean triples all conforming to the following equation:

$4(R+3) + (R+2)^2 = (R+4)^2$

I say quasi, because if you deliberately restrict yourself to picking $R$ such that $R+3$ is also a square, then it generates Pythagorean triples, though this isn't necessary for the answer to the original question.
It turns out that a Pythagorean triple is always involved in the solution to the original equation, namely such that:

$(2n + t)^2 = (n + m)^2 + (t+3n+m)(t+n-m)$

The last part of this equation, $(t+3n+m)(t+n-m)$, must equal a square. Then $f$ is given by $C - 2nm - m^2$ where $C$ is the original composite number to be factored.

Each term in the quasi-Pythagorean equation has a multiplier, which is $((2m-t)/R)^2$. Though this post doesn't cover the workings-out in much depth, that is basically it. It would take several pages more to go over it step-by-step, which I don't have time to do now, but may revisit at some point in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Caveat: None of this actually tells you how to find $m$ analytically though, which is something I'm still working on.